# Search a list fine text in between <TEXT> and </TEXT>

Tags: python-3.x, list, search

This is a processed html file and in a python list variable. It also has some line breaks - so the text is in multiple lines. The list is not tokenised.
There are multiple sets of "TEXT" and "/TEXT" in side angle bracket (html tags).
I want to extract the text in between those matching pairs and append them to another list. Appreciate experts help here.

```py
with gzip.open(.....)
    texty = []
    for i, line in enumerate(opened_file): #reading file
      texty.append(line.strip(' \t\n\r')
```

After reading it could be joined as below:

```
lines.append(' '.join(line))
```

Variable texty/lines has `<TEXT>` and `</TEXT>` repeated several times. I need to process this texty or lines and extract the contents and append to another variable (eg lines from the code above). Eventually this new content will be written to a CSV file of two or three columns under a header "ContentK" -

Update:
Beautiful soup failed due to its not a byte object but a list.
Would this fix:

```
with gzip.open(.....)
  texty = ''
  for i, line in enumerate(opened_file): #reading file
    texty.join(line.strip(' \t\n\r')
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

To parse this text I recommend to use HTML parser such as `beautifulsoup`. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = """
This text I don't want
XXX <TEXT> I want
this text </TEXT> YYY
ZZZ <text> and this too </text>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

out = [t.text for t in soup.find_all("text")]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[' I want\nthis text ', ' and this too ']
```

Comment: Beautiful soup failed due to its not a byte object but a list.

Comment: @user4504270 Read the file to a string and put this string to `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Would this fix?  with gzip.open(.....)
    texty = ''
    for i, line in enumerate(opened_file): #reading file
      texty.ajoin(line.strip(' \t\n\r')

Comment: Sorry the format was lost above. So I updated in my OP.

Comment: I am getting several of '', '', - thoughts on cleaning it?

Comment: is there a reason you put them inside square brackets? This adds \n and ', in it. strip('\n.) is not cleaning the newline. Another way to do this?